# What will be the output of the following list code execution in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am adding five objects in the list with the help of for loop. I am initializing my object outside the for loop. In the body of for loop i am changing the object setter properties and adding it in the list. The output with this is: It will add five objects but all have the same attributes even after setting the different values for the attribute.

See the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class ASD {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List list = new ArrayList<A>();
        System.out.println("Before Insert List is " + list);
        A obj = new A();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            obj.setA(new Random().nextInt(10));
            list.add(obj);
        }

        System.out.println("After Insert List is " + list);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            A prObj = (A) list.get(i);
            System.out.println("Values are" + prObj.getA());
        }
    }
}

class A {
    int a;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

If I initialize A's object inside the for loop then it will add five objects and also changes the attribute for the objects. Can anyone explain this behaviour

Comment: Could you please indent the code so that it is readable?

Comment: It would appear you don't understand objects. You have exactly one of them which you keep modifying. And you've added to the list 5 times. I would highly suggest a beginner's book on programming / Java or the tutorials provided by Oracle.

Comment: There is only one object A and you are modifying the same object attribute so it is overwriting, if you create object inside for every tine new object is created and store in list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing this -

```
A obj = new A();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    obj.setA(new Random().nextInt(10));
    list.add(obj);
```

you are actually adding reference to the same object after changing it's attribute *setA*.
That way, all of the list elements have reference to the same object (*with same value of `a`*).

You need to add new objects if you want to have different values -

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        obj = new A(); // new object
        obj.setA(new Random().nextInt(10));
        list.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have created just one instance and setting it several times inside the `for` loop.Create a new instance of `A` inside the `for` loop, not outside it

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    A obj = new A();
    obj.setA(new Random().nextInt(10));
    list.add(obj);
}
```